# How to read bytes in a dict comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I think this code could be a dict comprehension :

```
payload = {}
           

for itemID in iter( functools.partial(decodePayload, ID=TAG_BYTE), 0):
    itemName = decodePayload(TAG_STRING)
    itemPayload = decodePayload(itemID)
    payload[itemName] = NBT(
        ID=itemID,
        payload=itemPayload
    )
    return payload
```

decodePayload is basically a fancy .__next__() for a bytearray iterator, and exists alongside it in another function. It decides how many bytes to read and how to decode them based on its one argument. It calls itself recursively a lot, because said array contains nested data.

This code is **inside** the decodePayload function, and recursively calls the function until it returns 0 (Which means this sequence is over, but the bytearray may not be).

itemID, itemName and itemPayload **ABSOLUTELY** need to be read in order.

Is what I want to do even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will note, yes, using a dict comprehension is possible, but your code is fine, readable, and pythonic as it is.

In any case, straight-frowardly,

```
return {
    decodePayload(TAG_STRING): NBT(ID=itemID, payload=decodePayload(itemID)
    for itemID in iter(functools.partial(decodePayload, ID=TAG_BYTE), 0)
}
```

However, since the order of your `decodePayload` calls matters, then the cleanest solution above will not work on Python versions below 3.8!

From the [What's New docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#other-language-changes):

> Dict comprehensions have been synced-up with dict literals so that the
> key is computed first and the value second.

Previously, this wasn't the case. Here's an example from a Python 3.7 interpreter:

```
>>> {print(f'key {i}'):print(f'value {i}') for i in range(3)}
value 0
key 0
value 1
key 1
value 2
key 2
{None: None}
```

And here is the fixed version from Python 3.8:

```
>>> {print(f'key {i}'):print(f'value {i}') for i in range(3)}
key 0
value 0
key 1
value 1
key 2
value 2
{None: None}
```

To force an order in previous versions, you could do something ugly like this:

```
return {
    k: v
    for itemID in iter(functools.partial(decodePayload, ID=TAG_BYTE), 0)
    for k, v in [(decodePayload(TAG_STRING), NBT(ID=itemID, payload=decodePayload(itemID))]

}
```

But honestly, at that point, just stick with what you have. Indeed, I think what you have is fine as it is anyway.

Comment: I think I'll stick with what I have, because either version of these would break my code ! The key needs to be read in between the two things that go in the value, which seems to be impossible

Comment: @AmyLucyRose huh? The key, `decodePayload(TAG_STRING)` is read in-between `itemId` and `payload=decodePayload(itemID)`, again, only if you are using Python 3.8 +, what version are you on?

Comment: I’m using 3.8, sorry I didn’t read well enough  I might use a comprehension, I’m not sure yet. This code needs refactoring anyway, although this particular function will probably mostly stay in place

Comment: @AmyLucyRose well, like I stated, I don't think you need to use a comprehension. It's getting to the point of being unreadable, and your for-loop is fine. For loops are perfectly pythonic